# Store token generated on fetch() with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api

From this code I get a token, I need to store the token to use in another fetch so I can refresh the token, what's the best way to do it?

I can only access the variable inside the function `.then`...

I would prefer to store the token in a encoded cookie, but I don't how to handle cookies em react, or how to encode or decode them.

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("theURL/api-token-auth/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: "EMAIL",
      password: "PASS"
    })
  })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.ok) {
        return res.json();
      } else {
        throw Error(res.statusText);
      }
    })
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        token: json
      });

      let token = this.state.token;
      console.log("var token: ", token);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)? You could put your token there, and check if there is a token in localStorage when you load the app.

Comment: You can use cookies with React as with any other JS app - or any other API like localStorage, for that matter. If you don't want to handle encoding and decoding directly, use third-party libraries that do that.

Comment: I didn't want localStorage becaus it's a bit insecure... @Tholle

Comment: Do you have any suggestion? @estus

Comment: I don't use cookies myself, only as a fallback for localStorage. You can check popular libs on Github. localStorage is less secure than cookies? Where did you get that? As for LS, there's store.js, localForage and a bunch of others.

Comment: Because anyone can change localStorage, right? But cookies don't... at least I learnt that

Comment: Well that's debatable. People do use both localStorage and cookies and none of them is fully secure IMO. But as @estus already pointed out, you can use cookies with React. All you need is a lib like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie to set a cookie after you have a token and use it whenever you want to make an XHR call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on localStorage, is a good place for store tokens.

`localStorage.setItem('token', 'userToken');`

And then to recover the value just do:
`const token = localStorage.getItem('token');`

Take a deeper look here:[Web Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Shouldn't this be enough to store the token in localStorage? `.then(json => { this.setState({ isLoaded: true, token: json }); let token = this.state.token; localStorage.setItem('token', token); }) .catch(error => console.error(error)); const token = localStorage.getItem('token');`

Comment: Can you post the entire conde?

Comment: I'll make it in another question @Dupocas